# How can I write raw binary data to duckdb from R?

Tags: sql, r, duckdb

My best guess is that this simply isn't currently supported by the `{duckdb}` package, however I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong/not in the in the intended way. Here's a reprex which reproduces the (fairly self-explanatory) issue:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())

# Note: this connection would work fine
# con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite())

DBI::dbCreateTable(
  conn = con,
  name = "raw_test",
  fields = list(file = "blob")
)

DBI::dbAppendTable(
  conn = con,
  name = "raw_test",
  value = data.frame(file = I(list(as.raw(1:3)))),
  field.types = list(file = "blob")
)

#> Error: rapi_execute: Unsupported column type for scan
#> Error: rapi_register_df: Failed to register data frame: std::exception
```

NB (1), I'm trying to find a way to write arbitrary R objects to SQL. To do this, I plan to serialise the objects in question to binary format, write to SQL, read back and unserialise. I also want to find a method that works reliably with as many SQL backends as possible, as I'm planning to create a package which allows the user to specify the connection.

NB (2), I've posted this as an [issue on the `duckdb` github](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/4116) as I have a feeling this is simply a bug/not yet a supported feature.

### Edit #1

I'm now more convinced that this is simply a bug with `{duckdb}`. From the documentation for `DBI::dbDataType()`:

> If the backend needs to override this generic, it must accept all basic R data types as its second argument, namely logical, integer, numeric, character, dates (see Dates), date-time (see DateTimeClasses), and difftime. If the database supports blobs, this method also must accept lists of raw vectors, and `blob::blob` objects.

`duckdb` certainly supports `blob` types, so as far as I can see, these objects should be writeable. Note, this code produces the same issue outlined above (using `blob::blob()` instead of `I(list())`:

```
DBI::dbAppendTable(
    conn = con,
    name = "raw_test",
    value = data.frame(file = blob::blob(as.raw(1:3))),
    field.types = list(file = "blob")
)

#> Error: rapi_execute: Unsupported column type for scan
#> Error: rapi_register_df: Failed to register data frame: std::exception
```

I'm leaving this open for now in case any kindly `duckdb` dev can confirm this is a bug/missing feature, or if anyone can suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it’s just a missing feature according to [this issue](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/discussions/3229)